# How can i add a video to youtube history?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I tried to add a YouTube video to my YouTube history, but none of my methods worked. There is no answer or information on the internet for this question, so I just want some information or maybe the solution to this problem.

I already tried YouTube playback statistics and YouTube watch time statistics, but nothing happened. Nothing was added or changed.

I also tried both of them, but nothing happened. Nothing was added or changed.

Comment: By anyway there is no answer, i will work alone on it and i believe allah and then i believe my self that i will find the solution so i will close this post as answered

All my regards for everyone and thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used Youtube API, but logically I think this souldn't be possible.

Generally speaking, any kind of history should not be tempered with it by an external system.

I doubt the Youtube API would expose an endpoint that let's you alter this history.

Most Google APIs are read only.

One thing you could maybe do is try to request the video directly with an http GET request as if you were trying to play the video in a browser, but it might not work if there's a captcha that shows up.

Comment: as first thanks for your answer but i dont talking just about youtube apis, i mean by anyway
maybe youtube's own requests or anything similar

Comment: additionally i have already tried to send get request but as i posted yesterday, you can take a look to my post at yesterday, no one answered my posts